# Strange function definition in C++ language

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-c++

As far as I know, C++ functions are defined as follows

```
return_type function_name( parameter list ) {
   //body of the function
}
```

But in some references, it can be seen that the functions are defined in this way.

```
void IRAM_ATTR onTimer() {
   portENTER_CRITICAL_ISR(&timerMux);
   interruptCounter++;
   portEXIT_CRITICAL_ISR(&timerMux);
}
```

Why is the **IRAM_ATTR** located between **void** and **ontimer**?

Is it possible to do this in standard C++?

Comment: This must be some kind of a custom macro, possibly invoking some compiler-specific extension. You'll need to look elsewhere in this header file for more clues.

Answer (score 1):

`IRAM_ATTR` is a preprocessor macro, which means it could expand to almost anything during compilation including an empty string.

> Is it possible to do this in standard C/C++?

In a trivial sense, yes, you can use `#define IRAM_ATTR` to whatever you want and generate valid C code.

More relevantly, what's happening here is that the code base you're working with has defined function attributes to control how the final memory map gets generated. If you trace down where `IRAM_ATTR` is defined, it's going to look something like this:

```
// Forces code into IRAM instead of flash.
#define IRAM_ATTR __attribute__((section(".iram1")))
```

The `__attribute__(())` keyword is a GNU extension that allows you to have finer grained control over all sorts of compiler behavior. In this case, it's the specific section where this function is placed. Unlike desktop platforms, on embedded systems it's extremely common to have a handful of different memory "banks" with different physical attributes where code and data can be placed. On your platform `IRAM` appears to be one of them.

Comment: The C++ form of this is `[[attribute]]` and compiler extensions with `[[gnu::section(".iram1")]]`.

Answer (score 1):

### What it does

Some quick googling shows it is defined [here](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/tools/sdk/esp32/include/esp_common/include/esp_attr.h#L26) (plus a few alternate files with identical declarations).

```c
// Forces code into IRAM instead of flash
#define IRAM_ATTR _SECTION_ATTR_IMPL(".iram1", __COUNTER__)

// Forces data into DRAM instead of flash
#define DRAM_ATTR _SECTION_ATTR_IMPL(".dram1", __COUNTER__)
```

### How it works

Conceptually it gives each function a variable named "iram1" with a unique number. The number provided by `__COUNTER__` is only used to satisfy the requirement of a value. The linker script can then detect this variable on certain functions in the later stages of compilation and change how they are formatted into the final binary.

### Why it is used

First off, this is based off of a cursory search on the macro combined with my personal knowledge. While I think I more or less correctly explain why it is used, there may be some slight inaccuracies and additional technical reasons for its inclusion.

As I understand it, this is required for a function to be used to receive CPU interrupts. If this was not included, we might not have a guarantee that the function is loaded into RAM for the full duration of code execution. Normally depending on the strategy being employed, code may be loaded from the disk as needed to reduce the memory overhead and allow the program to start before the entire binary has finished loading. However, this would cause problems for a CPU interrupt since it can be called at any time with little to no notice. Halting the CPU to fetch a file from the storage would likely incur a significant and noticeable delay. I am not too familiar with CPU interrupts to say for sure, but I would not be surprised if the CPU simply ignored the interrupt if the function was not loaded into memory.

### Your example

In your example, we can infer that `onTimer` has been given `IRAM_ATTR` since it is triggered by a CPU interrupt. It seems likely that this may be because this interrupt is triggered by the firing of a clock signal.

The usage of `portENTER_CRITICAL_ISR` and `portEXIT_CRITICAL_ISR` appear to be there to prevent undefined behavior if another thread is using `interruptCounter` when the function is triggered. However I can't help, but wonder if this could produce a deadlock of in the `timerMux` is locked when the interrupt is triggered on a single core device (citation needed).

Answer (score 1):

The `IRAM_ATTR` is a macro telling the linker to load the function into IRAM (Instruction RAM) for execution. Typically, for MCU (ESP32 in this case), program is executed directly from flash instead of load it into RAM for execution like your normal PCs. So in order to load the code into IRAM for execution, it needs to explicitly telling the linker to do so.

The `IRAM_ATTR` is specific for ESP32/ESP8266 architecture. Read [Memory Types](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/memory-types.html) to understand the various types of memories in ESP32, it has more detail explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Certain compilers and operating systems support function decoration. A notable example in Windows is

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

Where `WINAPI` is a macro that expands during preprocessing, often to `__stdcall` or something else, depending on the target.